# Using MPI, how can I synchronize the end of inter-dependent processes?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, synchronization, mpi, deadlock

Ok, the title sounds confusing but the concept is not too bad.  Basically, I have two processes that are running (let's call them process 0 and process 1).  They both run a function at the same time.  While this function is running, sometimes they need data from each other.  So process 0 sometimes requests data from process 1 and vice versa.  Since they rely on each other, I don't want one process to finish before the other.  If process 0 finishes its work, it should continue checking for requests from process 1 (otherwise process 1 won't be able to finish).  After both processes have finished their work, only then should they proceed.

I'm having trouble implementing this.  Right now, I have each process send all other processes a notification when it finishes (so process 1 sends a notification to process 2 when its work is done).  Then I have a loop that is supposed to continue until it receives a notification from all the other processes.  Only then should the loop exit and the process continue.  However, this isn't working.  The processes keep going before the others have finished.  I feel like there's probably a much simpler way to do this that I'm not thinking of.

I'm a complete newbie to MPI, so I hope I've explained this properly.  Also, this needs to work for any number of processes, not just two.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let a controller do the work: A centralized piece of code that is hearing all processes,  so if a given procees need to exit then it ask the controller if it can do that, the controller.

Comment: Is there a way that I could avoid that?  This is for a school project and one of the requirements is that all processes are peers, and there can be no controller or master process.  Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: Sounds like you need a barrier synchronisation, e.g. `MPI_Barrier(somecomm);` where `somecomm` is some communicator that both processes are member of. A barrier call blocks and returns only once all processes in `somecomm` have made the call.

Comment: There is no standard solution here. The approach depends on what *"the processes rely on each other"* means. You have to differentiate between point to point, collective and master/slave. The finishing should follow the general pattern of communication. A centralized controller is often undesirable because it limits scalability. It would be good if you can provide more information - in form of code. Why don't you provide an [mcve] showing you have unsuccessfully tried. That way we can help much better.